Firefox UI font too big after 24.04 upgrade
I upgraded to 24.04 from 23.10 last week. Most stuff is fine. I am however noticing that some Firefox fonts are bigger than they were before. I see these cases:

Address bar
Bookmark bar and submenus
Some website content fonts, like on GitHub

These font sizes seem to correlated to the interface font as set in Gnome tweaks. However, the interface font appears smaller in the actual Gnome UI than in Firefox. So either Gnome is downsizing or Firefox is upsizing.
I can't seem to find any settings for this in Firefox, not even the usual page font settings nor in about:config. I also looked in dconf-editor to see if there were any additional font controls that weren't in Gnome tweaks.
I'm not sure what changed from Gnome 45 to 46 (or Ubuntu or Firefox), so it's a little hard to figure out what to look for.
Note: I am using Firefox via deb and not via Snap.
Firefox:

Various Gnome:




Not sure exactly how to fix your balancing of fonts but can add some help. I believe it is a gnome balancing issue because I also recently installed 24.04 but do not have Gnome installed. Without Gnome, there are no issues with font sizes in Firefox. Maybe try uninstalling Gnome, rebooting and seeing if the issue persists to confirm this.

I'm not planning to leave Gnome, so this isn't really an option for me. But if I were using KDE or another DE, this would be acceptable.

I suggest that you run Firefox outside of the snap system (/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox) to see if that’s related.
The non-confined Firefox won’t find your parameters and bookmarks though, because they’re normally in a snap-specific location, but don’t worry, they’re not deleted and you will find them back as soon as you start Firefox in the usual way.

I am not using the Snap version, actually. I'll edit my question to specify that. Sorry about leaving that out.

@siride I doubt it will change anything, but maybe try the snap version then… Did you test how it fares with a new start of Firefox ? I mean like it was run for the first time. Another thing that comes to mind is what session are you using, X or Wayland ?
